# Using an arrayAdapter outside of the MainActivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-layout

I have been trying to use an arrayAdapter outside of my main activity in a class called Client(). I realize that the constructor for the arrayAdapter is ArrayAdapter(context, layout_id, textview_id, items) so I have passed in the context from the mainActivity into the constructor for my Client class. For the layout_id I understand that it has to be a textView id so I passed an arbitrary textview from the mainActivity into the ArrayAdapter constructor then tried to update the UI via a handler like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, textView.getId(), clients);
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

I receive the following error most likely how I have passed the textView Id.

```
 1340-1340/package E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080040 type #0x12 is not valid
```

I know if I were to do this from an Activity I could just pass it in like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But How do I do this outside of an `Activity`?

EDIT: Extra Info:
I have my textView inside my activity_main like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I get the textView within my MainActivity.java like this:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Then pass it into my client class like this:

```
 cThread = new Client(ip, port, context, activity, mHandler, listView, tv);
```

Comment: It is not an item ID from within a view.  It is a layout ID to the layout file that will represent each row.

Comment: post more code. You are using an overloaded method - and you think you're passing an object but it thinks it's a reference ID

Comment: I don't think there is any good and safe solution to populate a list outside of an activity because it's not really a good practice. Can you do what you need to do in you client and then, go back to you activity with your items list by using a callback ?

Answer (score 1):

In you question you are referencing one constructor :
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects)

but in your code you are using an other one
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)

The one you are using expect a layout resource id and not a view id.

!!Be careful, I don't know what you mean by "an arbitrary textview id" but the textview must exist in the layout you use to instantiate the arrayAdpater .

Answer (score 0):

Hi just replace `textView.getId()` **by** `R.id.textView` in the first line of  your code